# Returning error from GeoServer WFS-T service if I cannot insert in the PostgreSQL database under the explained conditions

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, postgresql

I know that if you try to insert a feature trying to insert as a string something that in the PostgreSQL database is a number you are getting error.

But I'm not too sure of the following situation:

Before possible insertion in the PostgreSQL database I plan on firing a trigger and check some things about a string, if it fulfills my conditions data Will be inserted, if not it won't.

But I'm not sure if there's a possible way so that if the insertion does not happen due to the trigger on PostgreSQL database not happening, it returns an error which can be caught in the client accordingly.

Is this possible to do? I'm using Leaflet to insert the data.

Comment: You can't insert with a WMS, you'll need a WFS-T service configured

Comment: @nmtoken, sorry I put it wrong, anyway would that be possible with an WFS-T one?

Comment: What will your trigger return if it fails?

Comment: @Ian Turton, didn't still think about it, but if I can capture in firebase any value that I tell the trigger to return it would be enough.